# how to set count based on content in react js

Tags: reactjs

Here I have attached some code plz find and give the correct solution how to solve the problem.
[image]

```
when we search the name, based on the name I want to display the count value.
```

for example, 3 names came, so 3 results found. In this way I want. The filter is working properly. only I want to track the record. Here is the code.

```
app.js

import Filter from './component/Filter';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Filter />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here i attached Filter.js component
Filter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Filter extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            searchTerm: "",
            names: [{
                "first_name": "Mack"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Andres"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Bee"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Donni"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Pippy"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Chrystel"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Etienne"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Elberta"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Brion"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Aurea"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Kerry"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Mervin"
              }, {
                "first_name": "Georgianna"
              }]
        }
    }

    render(){
       return <>
       <div className="filterList">
            <input className="slice-item" type="fileName" placeholder="search name" onChange= {event => {this.setState({searchTerm: event.target.value})}} />
            <div className="slice-item resultCount">
                <span className="num">0</span> results found
            </div>
       </div>
       
        {
            this.state.names.filter((name) => {
                if(this.state.searchTerm === ""){
                    return name;
                }else if(name.first_name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())){
                    return name;
                }
            }).map((name) =>(
                <h4>{name.first_name}</h4>
            ))
        }
       </>
    }
}

export default  Filter;
```

1. Almost done.I want to apply only result count.

   ```
    Anyone can plz post your answer.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the filter logic outside the return to get the list of names. Then the length of that list is the number of results.

```
render(){
       const filteredNames = this.state.names.filter((name) => {
                if(this.state.searchTerm === ""){
                    return name;
                }else if(name.first_name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())){
                    return name;
                });
       const renderResultCount = this.state.searchTerm && this.state.searchTerm.length > 0;
       return <>
       <div className="filterList">
            <input className="slice-item" type="fileName" placeholder="search name" onChange= {event => {this.setState({searchTerm: event.target.value})}} />
            <div className="slice-item resultCount">
                { renderResultCount ? <span className="num">{filteredNames.length}</span> results found : null}
            </div>
       </div>
       
        {
            filteredNames.map((name) =>(
                <h4>{name.first_name}</h4>
            ))
        }
       </>
    }
```

Edit: Added conditionall render of text due to authors request in comments

Comment: Thank u very much. it's so much helpful

Comment: One more small task. I can't do it. Initially, the "20 results found or some number results found" that div must be hidden. when I will start to search for something then it will display. If I clear the search box again it will be hidden. How to implement ?

Comment: Do I understand correctly if you want to display X results found only if someone has focus on the search search field?

Comment: I mean if the search box is empty then it will hide.if I shall start to write something then only it will display. again if I cleared the character from the search box again it will hide

Comment: either on div or span you want to remove from view you would conditionally render if this.state.searchTerm.length > 0, Can update my anser if you need it

Comment: Answer is updated. The renderResultCount is a bool that determines if we want to render the text

Answer (score 0):

If you store the filter logic in a variable, you can access its length. This should work:

```
render() {
const names = this.state.names.filter((name) => {
  if (this.state.searchTerm === '') {
    return name;
  } else if (
    name.first_name
      .toLocaleLowerCase()
      .includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
  ) {
    return name;
  }
});

return (
  <>
    <div className='filterList'>
      <input
        className='slice-item'
        type='fileName'
        placeholder='search name'
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <div className='slice-item resultCount'>
        <span className='num'>{names.length}</span> results found
      </div>
    </div>

    {names.map((name) => (
      <h4>{name.first_name}</h4>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have converted into functional component, hope this one helps.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

export default function Filter() {
    const [result,handleResult] = useState([]);
    const [searchTerm,handleSearchTerm] = useState('');
    var names = [{
        "first_name": "Mack"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Andres"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Bee"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Donni"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Pippy"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Chrystel"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Etienne"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Elberta"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Brion"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Aurea"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Kerry"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Mervin"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Georgianna"
      }]

    function handleSearch(e){
       let search = handleSearchTerm(e.target.value);
       findName(search);
    }

      function findName(){
        let result = names.filter((name) => {
            if(this.state.searchTerm === ""){
                return name;
            }else if(name.first_name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())){
                return name;
            }
        })
        handleResult(result);
      }
    return (
         <div className="filterList">
            <input className="slice-item" type="fileName" placeholder="search name" onChange= {handleSearch} />
            <div className="slice-item resultCount">
            <span className="num">{result.length}</span> results found
            </div>
            {result.map((item)=>(
                    <h4>{item.first_name}</h4>
            ))}
       </div>
    )
}
```